# wxMaxima: set formatting for rational powers

Tags: wxmaxima

I was wondering if there is some way to use `texput` to tell Maxima how to format powers when they are rational expressions.

e.g. I would like

```
tex1(2^(2/5)); 
  > 2^{2 / 5}
```

instead of the default `2^{ \frac{2}{5} }`.

Can this be done?